# How get int from hex with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, encoding, char, int, hex

I have char with hex value `'\xa1'`, it's 161, and how I can get 161 in `int value`?

This doesn't work for me:

```
char a = '\xa1';
int b = a;
```

And I have a `uint8_t buffer[4]`, it reads bytes from `NSInputStream`, with hex value like this, how I can get array with int values from this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` is signed (where the high bit designates the number as negative). You apparently want an `unsigned char`, so either:

```
unsigned char a = '\xa1';
int b = a;
```

Or

```
char a = '\xa1';
int b = (unsigned char) a;
```